# How to save a text file present in asset folder of android app to the local directory of android phone as text or pdf file?

Tags: android

I have saved some text files in asset folder of android apk , whenever user opens the app which is having list of filenames ,if he  clicks on a filename corresponding file opens from asset folder ,

Now I want to let user save that file in text or pdf format to his local directory so that he can transfer it or use it or modify it according to his choice

EDIT : I just want to know the api needed ,not the whole code

Comment: Show something what you have tried instead of asking for code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to copy something from assets to storage

```
 private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
              in = assetManager.open(filename);
              File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
              out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
              copyFile(in, out);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }     
            finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
          out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Reference : [Move file using Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/MoveaFile.htm)